# "For each attribute, give the class it is."

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently reading and studying Python with the guidance of the awesome book "Learn Python The Hard-Way...".

Currently att OOP, Object Oriented programming. And one exercise says this:

> 1. For each class, give its name and what other classes it inherits from.
> 2. Under that, list every function it has and the parameters they take.
> 3. List all the attributes it uses on self.
> 4. **For each attribute, give the class it is.**

I am having trouble with the last one. I don't quite understand it. And I am a resourceful guy, so I have tried searching online to no avail. So why not do this, when most of my questions got awesome answers from searching on this site.

So the question 4. Or exercise 4. And while we're at it, I would be thankful*1000*thanks_for_ex4. if you would explain the other 3 to me. So I know I am doing them right too.

Comment: You can get the type of an object - which is the class - using the `type` function. With this, if you already solved 3, 4 should be easy. :-)

Comment: Are you after a programmatic solution, or are you just reading code?

Comment: The exercise is saying read code and do the above things. (1 to 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I borrowed an example class from [this website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

```
class Employee:
   'Common base class for all employees'
   empCount = 0

   def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary
      Employee.empCount += 1

   def displayCount(self):
     print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

   def displayEmployee(self):
      print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary
```

Now let's work through those questions

> 1) For each class, give its name and what other classes it inherits from.

This class happens to not inherit from another class. Nor do we have another class that inherits from it. As an example, if a subclass of `Employee` was `Secretary` (which would be a specific type of employee):

```
class Secretary(Employee):
    # blah blah
```

> 2) Under that, list every function it has and the parameters they take.

There are only two methods in this class, and neither take any additional parameters

```
def displayCount(self):
def displayEmployee(self):
```

> 3) List all the attributes it uses on self.

The two attributes of this class are `name` and `salary`

```
def __init__(self, name, salary):
    self.name = name
    self.salary = salary
```

> 4) For each attribute, give the class it is.

The two attributes are `name` and `salary`, which should be `str` and `int` respectively

```
>>> name = 'Bob'
>>> type(name)
<type 'str'>

>>> salary = 50000
>>> type(salary)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I get it now. When he asks "For each attribute, give the class it is." He means what type it is. But it's weird, no where in that chapter on classes and OOP does he even take that up. Maybe I am missing something. Thanks..

So conclusion. For each attribute, give the class it is -> Means -> Say the attributes type...
? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, in this context the "type" and "Class" are interchangeable terms.

Answer (score 1):

Every thing in python has a type - which that is str (string), int, float etc - so :

if you have a class defined as :

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.attr1 = 3
       self.attr2 = 5.7
       self.attr3 = "Hello"
       self.attr4 = ["Hello", "Goodbye"]
       self.attr5 = {"Greeting":"Hello"}
```

in this case :

```
  attr1 is of type int
  attr2 is of type float
  attr3 is of type str 
  attr5 is of type list
  attr6 is of type dict
```

Note : That since in python you don't declare the type of the attributes before you assign to them, the type is only determined when that attribute gets a value. It is also entirely valid python to change the type of an attribute - so your code could do this :

```
   self.attr3 = 17.6
```

thus changing attr3 from a str to a float - whether this is a good idea is a design decision you must make in your program - hint - it probably isn't.

Note 2 - calling your attributes attr1 to attr6 is a supremely bad idea in real code.

Comment: Thanks man. I get it now. When he asks "For each attribute, give the class it is." He means what type it is. But it's weird, no where in that chapter on classes and OOP does he even take that up. Maybe I am missing something. Thanks..

So conclusion. For each attribute, give the class it is -> Means -> Say the attributes type...
? 
Thanks in advance.